# Initializing a string array as an argument in a method call in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, initialization, parameter-passing

If I have a method like this:

```
public void DoSomething(int Count, string[] Lines)
{
   //Do stuff here...
}
```

Why can't I call it like this?

```
DoSomething(10, {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

What would be the correct (but hopefully not the long way)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can do this :

```
DoSomething(10, new[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

provided all the objects are of the same type you don't need to specify the type in the array definition

Comment: Perfect! Could you explain why the new[] is required though? If I did: string[] MyString = {"One", "Two", "Three"}; it works just fine?

Comment: its just the way the syntax works. you cant do this : var x = string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"}; but you can do this var y = new[]  {"One", "Two", "Three"};

Comment: these articles are very useful. object initializers make code sooo much cleaner http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx and for more on your original question see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047(VS.80).aspx#cs3spec_topic7

Answer (score 11):

If  `DoSomething` is a function that you can modify, you can use the [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword to pass in multiple arguments without creating an array.  It will also accept arrays correctly, so there's no need to "deconstruct" an existing array.

```
class x
{
    public static void foo(params string[] ss)
    {
        foreach (string s in ss)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        foo("a", "b", "c");
        string[] s = new string[] { "d", "e", "f" };
        foo(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./d.exe 
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: This is also a brilliant suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DoSomething(10, new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct it while passing it in like so:

```
DoSomething(10, new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create it using [ ], like this:

```
DoSomething(10, ["One", "Two", "Three"]);
```