# Array as a parameter implicit conversion

Tags: c#, arrays

Initializing an array is ok in these 3 cases

```
string[] To = { "one@g.com", "two@g.com" };
string[] To = new[] { "one@g.com", "two@g.com" };
string[] To = new string[] { "one@g.com", "two@g.com" };
```

But when using it as a parameter the first option is not valid
so this is valid

```
MethodWithAnArrayParam(new string[] { "hi@t.com", "hi@t.com" });
MethodWithAnArrayParam(new [] { "hi@t.com", "hi@t.com" });
```

This gives an error

```
   MethodWithAnArrayParam({ "hi@t.com", "hi@t.com" });
```

Why?

Comment: What makes you think its invalid?  What is the method signature for `.Send()`?

Comment: The posted code does not help much

Comment: Because `{ "one@g.com", "two@g.com" }` is not a valid C# array initializer. You need to tell C# which collection to build, array is not the default collection type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing a string array in a method call as a parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416500/initializing-a-string-array-in-a-method-call-as-a-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't use an “inline” array in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509177/cant-use-an-inline-array-in-c)

Comment: Because this is how the c# language defines an array literal. Just the curly brackets don't define an array literal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921844/how-to-return-an-array-literal-in-c-sharp

Comment: @oliver That's not a literal.

Comment: @Servy: okay, maybe not by strict definition of the language standard... but in a more casual sense meaning a character sequence that translates to an initial value of a data structure

Comment: @oliver The term for that is a constructor, or potentially an initializer.  A literal is a *value* of an object that is known at compile time.  There are only a few types that have meaningful literals, just strings and numeric types (and also `null` and `default(...)`).

Comment: Why? Because that's how the language was designed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arrangement declarations are made using the keyword new**

Try this

```
string TO = new string[]{ "one@g.com", "two@g.com" };
```

Also you can make use of generic arrays

```
var TO = new[]{ "one@g.com", "two@g.com" };
```

The data type of the same is given automatically automatic according to the value given:

```
new [] { "Hello "," World "} string array
new [] {0, 1, 2} int array
...
```

All this is invalid because at no time you tell the compiler that it is an Array, since {} has several different uses

```
emailProvider.Send("hello", { "one@g.com", "two@g.com" }, null, "subject");

emailProvider.Send("hello", (new string[] { "hi@t.com", "hi@t.com" }), null, "subject");
```

You can not create a statement without shadow and unassigned in the place of a parameter

```
bool Send(string message, string[] to, string[] bccTo, string subject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
new[]{ "one@g.com", "two@g.com" }
```

Edit: Or you can use

```
new string[]{ "one@g.com", "two@g.com" }
```

See: [Implicit Typed Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays)